# hasmany joining is not working in CI 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to join users(teacher) table to courses table .

One teacher has many courses ,i tried to make has many joining in CI 3 but its returning only one records , there are many records in DB of that user(teacher).
I am posting some of my codes .

```html
            $this->db->join("courses","users.user_id=courses.teacher_id");
            $this->db->where('teacher_verify',"false"); 
            $query= $this->db->get('users');
            echo "<pre>";print_r($query->result());exit;
           return  $pending_courses= $query->result();
```

Is there any error?

Anyone can suggest me ?
Thank you .

Comment: what you now get as result ?

Comment: I am getting only one course but there are 5 courses of that user.

Comment: I think i am doing it in wrong way

Comment: check the answers below

Answer (score 0):

Specify table name in where condition.Like this..

```
$this->db->select('*');//OR specify columns that you want 
$this->db->from("users");
$this->db->join("courses","users.user_id=courses.teacher_id");
$this->db->where('table_name.teacher_verify',"false");//specify table name
$query = $this->db->get();
print_r($query->result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join("courses","users.user_id = courses.teacher_id");
$this->db->where('XYZ.teacher_verify',"false"); # XYZ -> should be (courses/users)
$query = $this->db->get();

if (count($query) > 0) {
    //$result = $query->result_array();
    print_r($result);

} else {
    $result =  false;
}
return $result;
```

Comment: If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)